# How to run a post request to an API from an HTML page (using a button linked to javascript code) when the API require certificate and user/password?

Tags: javascript, api, post, postman

I want to add some javascript code into a HTML page that allow any user with access to that web page to run the available post requests there to an API. These post requests run well in Postman but I'm not sure how can I run this kind of requests using javascript since this API requires not only a certificate (with a passphrase) but also an additional credential pair (username and password) which in Postman are configured in a very intuitive way on the appropriate menus.

Can someone enlighten me how can I run these requests from a web page using javascript? Maybe share some sample code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The credentials aren't the problem, as long as the user knows them and is able to submit them when sending the request. The problem is the certificate... HTTP requests are sent by the browser, therefore the browser must be able to fetch the certificate and must know the passphrase - obviously a security issue. Spontaneous and with the given information, I definitly would advise against a frontend only solution! But please show us the Postman config and some more API information.

Comment: _"Maybe share some sample code?"_ - creating code in many different languages, based on your actual request, is a feature Postman has already build-in ...

Comment: Didn't knew this! Thanks! I'm already trying it :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use **fetch** or **axios** to handle the request with js

and for using a button linked to javascript code :
you can use `onclick`

I know this from your question and anything else you can ask me

Comment: I used the Postman functionality to create the code (javascript fetch) of my request and I got the following result:

Comment: `var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic 123xpto321");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "path": "/Customers/Organisation/organisation_adm/Account Management/Account Balance/Accounts",
  "outputType": "pdf"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.url/my-endpoint", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));`

Comment: Now, with the code above, I'm not sure how the certificate part is being deal with and I'm not sure how to get the result of the request. The result of the code is the error message: `net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`